# gradle 6.4 build with lombok 1.18.12 not generating getters and setter

Tags: java, gradle, getter-setter

Tried adding

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

and specified version in versions.gradle

```
lombokVersion="1.18.12"
```

Still compilation is failing with missing getter/setters.
Used --debug option and extracted arguments passed to java compiler and executed with javac and compilation went fine.
Tried overriding java compiler option via gradle command line option and via following properties

```
compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac'
```

Still no luck. It still seems to be using internal groovy compiler org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler
Anyone ran into similar issue?

Comment: What is the error? Please share the error and sample reproducible code if possible.

Comment: When we execute `gradle build`, compilation fails with object.getXXX() not found where the object/class is annotated with `@Getter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added lombok dependencies to common/build.gradle

```
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
```